# What does the "[Warning] Item base information definitely needs to be promoted" want me to do?

Tags: publishing-service

While attempting to debug an item that is not publishing to the web database, I checked the Sitecore Publishing Service's (3.1 Update-1/3.1.1, at the time, since upgraded to 3.1.3) publishing logs.

In the logs I found the following entry, for a total of three Sitecore items:

```
[Warning] Item base information definitely needs to be promoted : 150eaa31-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-54a8f3e22c6a ("IMG_5527[1]")
```

Each item was returned twice - my assumption is because we have two publishing targets. These were all Media Library items (images). None of the later log entries referenced back to these.

Is anything necessary to do with this, or can it safely be ignored if there are no errors?